# Как в windows 10 убрать панель задач?

Tags: windows

Не скрыть а именно убрать !

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А оставить [rocketdock](http://rocketdock.com/)

Comment: А в чём разница между «скрыть» и «убрать»?

Comment: убрать - значит панели нету ! т.е выключена через редактор реестра , скрывается через стандартную функцию

Comment: Ну, а если она убрана и её не видно, в чём тогда отличие?

Comment: отличие в том что её нету , надо заменить на другую панель

Comment: Что значит заменить на другую, на месте старой панели будет размещена написанная вами?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Поздновато, но все же. Есть маленькая утилита Nircmd.

1. скачать [ссылка](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html)
2. Распаковать архив в любое место.
3. Создаем ярлык и указываем путь к распаковываемому файлу.
4. После заходим в свойства ярлыка, в поле "Объект" вписываем код

   `nircmd.exe win show class "Shell_TrayWnd"` - показать панель задач

   `nircmd.exe win hide class "Shell_TrayWnd"` - убрать панель задач

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S: Область убранной панель задач не будет заполнятся! Для все работало, как надо, нам нужно скрыть панель, после запустить наш Ярлык.

Comment: Работает только с одним монитором, который указан основным. На втором мониторе панель остается. Тестировалось на версии 1709.